# date format differs when we change calender in setting

Tags: iphone

I am showing the date field in the `UILabel` the problem is when i change the setting of `ipad` 
using
 `settings->international->calender`

and change it to Buddhist from `gregorian` the date format differs.

How do i fix this issue so that it show the date format in `gregorian` only even when calender is changed?

Comment: use a custom `NSDateFormatter` to format the dates, I guess it will help you.

Comment: Yes, use NSDateFormatter and specify the desired locale and format.